# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Hello everyone I have this problem

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\right)$$

I try to find some function to squeeze this but it seems that it does not work ( maybe I do it wrong? ).
[image]

Also, i try to simplify the function inside the sum too but I don't know what to process next.

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+k+1}}{\sqrt {n+k}}\right)-\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+k}}{\sqrt {n+k+1}}\right)$$

Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for a limit or are you trying to prove convergence?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I'm trying to find the limit

Comment: Try to apply AM-GM to the close for you got in the last .

Comment: hint: start from $\frac{1}{n+1+k} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+k)(n+1+k)}} \le \frac{1}{n+k}$, show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cdots}} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$S=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\right)\sim \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{n+k}\right).$$
$$S= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+k/n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x}=\log 2.$$

Comment: @Z Ahmed. From where the "~" relation?